# How to redirect with wildcard in route

Tags: php, laravel

How to redirect with a variable in the route:

```
$id = 8;
return redirect('/userpage/{$id}');
```

The route:

```
Route::get('/userpage/{id}', 'UserController@userpage');
```

The controller:

```
public function userpage($id)
{
    return $id;        
}
```

This displays {$id}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append the id to the url.

```
return redirect('/userpage/' . $id);
```

Or using double quoted strings

```
return redirect("/userpage/{$id}");
```